# Take a screenshot and then save it to the camera roll. Swift 4.2, Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have found a source code from the internet to take a screenshot from current screen and then save it to the camera roll. But it gives an error when I click the button below

```
@IBAction func btnTakeScreenShot(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.takeScreenshot()
}

open func takeScreenshot(_ shouldSave: Bool = true) -> UIImage? {
    print("takeScreenshot")
    var screenshotImage :UIImage?
    let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
    layer.render(in:context)
    screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    if let image = screenshotImage, shouldSave {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
    }
    return screenshotImage
}
```

Here is the screenshot about the error:
[image]

I have two questions:

(1) Should I give any permission from Build Settings window in Xcode user to save it to the camera roll? If yes can you say exactly what is it? (Permission like hitting HTTP links: `App Transport Security Settings, Allow Arbitrary Loads` ..)

(2) Do you have any idea why this source code gives an error? And does this source code work fine to get screenshot and save it to the camera roll?

```
Swift 4.2, Xcode 10
```

Comment: Can you show full stack trace?

Comment: Actually, i just noticed this output: 2018-10-04 13:10:06.230218+0300 replayApp[14477:4979669] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data. @IlyaKharabet

Comment: Just add NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key to your Info.plist file.

Comment: I just noticed but actually, it was one of the question in my post: (1) Should I give any permission from Build Settings window in Xcode user to save it to the camera roll? If yes can you say exactly what is it? (Permission like hitting HTTP links: App Transport Security Settings, Allow Arbitrary Loads ..) Thanks! @IlyaKharabet

Comment: There is no permission for photo library in Build Settings. But you can ask for permission when app is running. Read about PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/1620736-requestauthorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the console for the below error,

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

So just add the `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` key in `Info.plist` file.